# How to get the non-file rightclick menu when files is in list view?

Tags: nautilus, files, context-menu, click-policy

When Gnome Files (nautilus) is in list view I sometimes still want to open the right-click menu that otherwise appears when you right-click into the empty space of a folder. (The one that lets you open the terminal etc.) Is that somehow possible?

Here a screenshot of the current situation: Where the menu of the corresponding *file* opens.

[image]

Comment: The actual problem is there is no space between files to be able to right click and get the right click context menu foir the current folder.
You can if you go to list view and scroll to the bottom, but in icon view it does not seem to be possible, there is no space between, like other file managers have. This is Nautilus's biggest failing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting a file while right-clicking so the right click applies to the file then selected. 
I see two ways to deal with the matter:

if your folder has not too many files, you can actually right click somewhere at the bottom of the list where there isn't any file.

If you're folder is 'full of files' (no empty space at the end of the list of files), then you can always go with keyboard shortcuts:

- if a file is selected, you can press F5 to deselect it (there should  be probably many other ways to do this).
- Then for right clicking without selecting any file, press Shift + F10

Comment: I didn't know about these shortcuts, thank you!

Answer (score 18):

You can get the right-click menu relative to the folder by right-clicking the folder in the "breadcrumbs" header.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+F10 also will reveal the right-click menu of the folder at any time.

Comment: @ToDo does that need some particular setting? I only actually tried it now, but i just get the following items upon the right-click in the breadcrumbs: "Open in new Tab", "Open in new Window", "Properties"

Comment: @vanadium Please add that as an own answer!

Comment: I didn't modify any setting to enable extra menu items.

Answer (score 0):

An imperfect workaround: Switch to the "icon" view temporarily.

[image: right click paste]

Comment: Hello @Community bot, I don't know how to make it more clear than that so you can understand it. Just switch to the "icon" view, and right click.

Comment: @Yvon Thanks for your answer, of course this is a way to do it, but it doesn't answer my question as I was specifically asking about the list view. In the icon view it is clearly possible.